# How to create a docker image of an existing R Shiny app in windows?

Tags: r, windows, docker, shiny

The dockerization process of an R shiny app is done through rocker/shiny image. I require to run the dockerization on an R shiny app from a windows system. The only problem is that rocker/shiny used for this process is a Linux based container. Therefore, I am unable to generate an image that runs on my windows system. Utilization of an external VPS or VM is not an option for me due to security reasons.

I have tried writing a docker file that would run for windows, but the problem is that the container is Linux based.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.5.1 

#installing R libraries

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'shinydashboard'), repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app/srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

#Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ['Rscript', 'app_run.R'] 
(original documentation mentions a .sh file which is not running on my system 
because of the Linux windows file path issues)
```

After running there 2 commands I expect my shiny app to run on localhost:8080

```
Get-Content Dockerfile | docker build -

docker run --name DOCKERapp -p 8080:8080 <image_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The base in your dockerfile is rocker/r-ver:3.5.1 and the based of this image is debian. You can check here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/r-ver/dockerfile

So in your dockerfile you need to use linux commands. You don't need to use windows commands.